# How to solve a typescript initialization issue in my Angular project?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular project and I'm trying to define a variable with the following type:

```
navbarLinks: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

but I get the following error:

```
Property 'navbarLinks' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

30   navbarLinks: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Now, I don't want to use this as a solution:

```
navbarLinks!: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Is there any other way I can fix this?

Comment: Either you initialize navbarLinks in the constructor, then you can just use your original code. Or you initialize it directly (i.e. not within a subscribe or then callback) in ngOnInit. That's what !: is for. Or you initialize it somewhere else, then it may be undefined so you use `navbarLinks?: QueryList<ElementRef>;`  and handle the undefined case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really do not want to set a default value to this property you need to adjust your type to

```
navbarLinks?: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

which is the same as

```
navbarLinks: QueryList<ElementRef> | undefined;
```

Another solution would be to give the property a default value. As I don't know what the `QueryList<T>` interface looks like, I can't really give you an example.